How can I correctly replace this section of a circuit powering 4 individually-switched lights?

I have 4 exterior lights, each independently controlled by switches on the interior of my house. During a renovation some of the wiring was damaged and needs to be replaced (the span between the two red lines).
This was previously wired with a 14/3 (L1, L2, L3) and 14/2 (L4, N) of old fabric sheathed NM. I was originally going to wire it the same way with new NM, but after thinking about it I'm pretty sure it's against code (2023) to run the neutral in a separate cable from the hots.
The wire runs from the switches down through ~4' of finished wall (that I'd prefer not to open), then ~20' down a joist bay in the basement (that's crumbling plaster and could be opened). It enters the "Exit Box" where it's connected to Type TW that's run through the exterior wall to the lights through ~150' of conduit along the outside of the building.
What is the most reasonable way for me to replace the damaged wiring while meeting code?
Some ideas I've considered:

Run 2 14/3 cables with a neutral in each, join neutrals at the exit box: I believe this is not allowed as it creates a parallel neutral path.
Run 2 14/3 cables with a neutral in each to the exit box. Run a second neutral through the exterior conduit to two of the lights: I believe this would be to code, but would be considerably more work. Ideally I would not have to touch any of the exterior wiring.
Run a single 14/5 cable: Does such a thing exist?
Run conduit between switches and exit box: Adds work since I would have to rip out the existing switch box and feed conduit through the finished wall and potentially rip down part of the basement ceiling.
Tape or wrap the two NM cables together: I think this would address any induced current issues, but it feels like something about this has got to be against code.


Note that ENT ("smurf tube") can be fished through finished cavity spaces

The only code compliant options are:

Run 2 14/3 cables with a neutral in each to the exit box. Run a second neutral through the exterior conduit to two of the lights: I believe this would be to code, but would be considerably more work. Ideally I would not have to touch any of the exterior wiring.
Run a single 14/5 cable: Does such a thing exist?
Run conduit between switches and exit box: Adds work since I would have to rip out the existing switch box and feed conduit through the finished wall and potentially rip down part of the basement ceiling.

Conduit (4) would be best.
2 and 3 both have problems. 2 requires work both inside and outside. 3 seems simple, but beware: If you search for 14/5, plenty of the options that come up include green as one of the wires instead of the usual case with 14/2 or 14/3 or 14/4 where there is a bare ground wire that is not included in the count. You need ground in any modern wiring, and you can't use green as anything other than ground.
Which means you are now up to 14/6. That is apparently commonly used for trailer wiring and other things. So the next challenge is to make sure that it is OK for use within your home. That means making sure it is rated for the correct voltage. Typical residential AC cables and wires are rated for 600V. Theoretically a rating of 125V would be enough. But in a look at cables made for automotive use, a typical rating is 60V, which is definitely not enough.
Some other cable I have found, which includes a 600V rating, is SOOW. That is meant for cordage, not for permanent wiring inside walls and ceilings.
Conduit is starting to look pretty good to me.

Imagine if 14/6 house cable was found, it would be expensive for being uncommon/special/custom made.

#2 would be code compliant as well, wouldn't it? In that case (unlike #1) the two neutrals coming out of the switch box are never joined so there are not parallel paths, just two sets of wires [Light 1 Hot, Light 2 Hot, Light 1/2 Neutral] and [Light 3 Hot, Light 4 Hot, Light 3/4 Neutral]. Or is there something else that puts it out-of-code?
Thank you for the response.

@jj50 You're right, that would work.

In the diagram there is only one neutral for all the light circuits.  Maybe since it's in conduit you could pull another one.  But IMO that's entrenching a problem that should not exist.  Get those things on a software timer divorced from the existing wall switches.

Maybe not the answer you're looking for but since conduit seems like the only reasonable approach and you don't want to use it, an alternative is to use smart switches. You just need a 14/2 between the boxes.  Put four smart controllers in the outside box or in a new box inside adjacent to it.   And four switches to control the controllers where the switches currently are. In fact if you do this you may not need any cable run the 24 ft. The outside box can be powered from anything nearby that's on a 15 amp breaker.  The wall switches and lights don't have to be on the same breaker.
Or ... Since these are outside lights you could just ditch the wall switches altogether. Put new semi smart switches (eg ZWave) on a wall near the outside box, but those are physicaly just a backup. Mainly control them with timers in your hub and with your phone.

This is a great idea! I had planned on one day adding some smart switches/relays so I could put them on a timer, but it had not occurred to me that it could solve this issue as well. Thanks!
